# Django, creating multiple identical fields in the same model

Tags: python, django

I am completely new to Django, so forgive me if this is the wrong approach. While I'm trying to learn Django, I like to do my own little practice problems to solidify my understanding.

Working with models I created the example model objects:

```
from django.db import models


class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        help_text="Name of Fruit or Vegetable"
    )
    food_group = models.CharField(
        max_length=9,


class Vitamins(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(
        Food,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    vitamin_A = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
    )
    .
    .
    .
    folate = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        help_text="Folic Acid"
    )
```

In my object, I have 5 identical fields that store text i.e. (Trace amounts, 5mg, No Information). However it seems tedious to type out every field. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you create a new record for each entry of Vitamin? I mean a Vitamin model with food (FK), name and folate? And while creating a entry you just create a new record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should take advantage of the relational database and create a model for Vitamin, with name and folate, something like this

```
from django.db import models


class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        help_text="Name of Fruit or Vegetable"
    )


class Vitamin(models.Model):
    food = models.ForeignKey(
        Food,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
    )
    folate = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        help_text="Folic Acid"
    )
```

And then for every Vitamin in the Food you create a record. It can be 1, 2 or N. This is very flexible and scaleable.

Comment: Thank you! I accepted the answer. I realize that I am stuck in a mindset where I am trying to force a spreadsheet into my models. I think every column in a spreadsheet needs it own field within an object. Instead of just thinking about creating a record of what I need and relating it to my object, which is much more flexible.